# Using mkdocs Github pages are not updating but gh-pages branch has the latest changes

Tags: github, github-pages, mkdocs

There are a few similar questions but none of the solutions mentioned in the other questions could solve my issue.

I am using `mkdocs` to publish github pages. command I am using is `mkdocs gh-deploy --clean`

This has worked correctly in the past. But now suddenly after making a minor spelling change to one of the pages, the changes are not reflected in the git pages website. Note that in gh-pages branch I can see the changes were pushed correctly.

Shouldn't gh-pages branch be in sync with github pages website all the time ?

What am I missing here ?

//EDIT:

To say this problem in other words, It is a static site which is built using mkdocs. If gh-pages branch has all the changes (and it works fine locally), then shouldn't it update the github pages site automatically. As I understand there is no build process involved for static github pages site.

Comment: A github repository url can be usefull for debug.

Comment: @DavidJacquel It is actually on github enterprise account so not public. But last 4~5 times it worked well. Now it is not working.

Comment: No code : no debug.  But, if you push to a (project repository)[https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/] in the `gh-pages` branch, any build failure is reported in `github.com/userName/repoName/settings` and in build failure emails. Maybe you can find some clues in those messages.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @DavidJacquel The problem was just that it took some time to update, some kind of cache for github pages. after a few hours it magically showed the latest contents from the repo.